# Does R perform automatic partial column match in data frame, if the column does not exists in the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

R is performing the automatic partial match with existing columns.
This is the code I ran...

```
a<-mtcars
## I get the results for this
a$mpg
## Surprisingly I am getting the results for which is same as a$mpg data
a$m
```

May I know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the `[[` i.e `a[["mpg"]]` to avoid partial matching

Comment: Better even: read `?"[.data.frame"`

Comment: thanks for the updates... May I know  how and why this partial matching is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `[[` or `[`, to subset without partial matching

```
a[["mpg"]]
a[, 'mpg']
```